# Offline anonymous electronic money systems and their cryptographical base

Tags: cryptocurrency

What **anonymous offline** electronic money systems exist and what are they based on? I know only one currently - [eCash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecash), based on [RSA blind signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature).

Comment: Are you sure such a system can even exist? I think that out of secure, anonymous and offline, you can only have two at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

http://faircash.org/technology/teleportation.html

> Due to the Digital Coin concept, a value transfer between payer and payee is realized by transferring ownership of the eCoin. An essential part is the way how this transfer is conducted: Following the cash paradigm, it needs to be done peer-to-peer and offline in a repeatable way. Such a transfer is called teleportation.